# How to set command name prefixed with -- in cobra

Tags: go, go-cobra

I want to create a command with name --list, but if I set --list as Use property of cobra.Command it does not works. Like bellow code does not works. Any help?

```
    list := &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "--list",
    Short: "Lists all data",
    Run: func(*cobra.Command, []string) {}
```

Comment: You cannot have a command name starting with `-` or `--`. Those are arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a command with a name starting with `-` or `--`, because in cobra these are flags. See the corresponding [source code](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/tree/eb3b6397b1b5d1b0a2cd66a9afe0520f480c0a87/command.go#L577) in the library, which removes them when [parsing](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/tree/eb3b6397b1b5d1b0a2cd66a9afe0520f480c0a87/command.go#L626) the command.